# JPA persist one-to-one persistence with non-existing entity from one side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have an old database where there are two tables with implicit association between them:

```
booking

- id
- name
... some other fields...
```

and

```
booking_info
- id
- booking_id
... some other fields...
```

Due to the current database design there no any constraints between these two tables, which means that one booking entry may exist without any booking_info entries and vice versa. `booking_id` in `booking_info` table is an implicit foreign key which refers to `booking` table (column `id`), but it also may refer to the absent booking.

I have created the following JPA mapping for these tables:

```
@Entity
public class Booking {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // getters & setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class BookingInfo {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "booking_id")
    private Booking booking

    // getters & setters

}
```

Now I need to be able to persist a `BookingInfo` entity even if there's no related `Booking` entry in the database.

```
BookingInfo bookingInfo = new BookingInfo();
bookingInfo.setId(1);
Booking booking = new Booking();
booking.setId(182); // let's say that there's no booking with id 182 in my database, but I still need to persist this bookingInfo
bookingInfo.setBooking(booking);

bookingInfoRepository.save(bookingInfo); // using Spring Data JPA
```

If I run this code then I get `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` since booking with id 182 is absent.

What would be the proper workaround for my case using JPA or Hibernate. 
Btw, I also tried to use Hibernate's `@NotFound` annotation. As a result, `save` method doesn't throw `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` and entity gets persisted int the database, but the problem is that `booking_id` in the database always null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you save the `Booking` object you create with id 182 first? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Joakim Because in my application I receive Booking and BookingInfo from a messaging broker, and often BookingInfo message comes before Booking. So in real life it may happen that I receive a BookingInfo notification and I need to persist it in my database, then I receive a Booking notification and I also need to persist it. The delay between these two events might be up to hours (e.g 24 hours).

Comment: Then you should not have the join in JPA if it doesn't exist in the database or  can't be supported by the business logic or have the join but store the booking id in a separate field until you receive the booking and have stored it in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure my answer will help you or not, but the result you are getting perfectly make sense. As you are setting a JPA object, and that object is not present, hence the null value is saved. 
If you want to save 182 as an integer, you don't do JPA relationship. Instead, you just use booking-id as an integer field in booking-info. And that makes sense because you actually do not have the relationship between those tables which the JPA is trying to achieve.

But I am sure you just want to save 182 and as well as maintain the JPA relationship. And I am sure you already know it, but DB integrity is not being maintained with the approach you are taking. I am sure there is enough reason behind that. But my recommendation would be applying proper constraints in the DB and then in JPA.